# Javascript return in the form of a link text of the url of a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a button contained within a sem_menu2.html page which in turn this page is contained within an iframe, how can I create a function that, once the button is clicked, returns me the name of the file contained in an href?

```
<div class="col-sm">
  <a target="frameapplication" href="/pages/applicazione.html">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="loadPage()">
      <i class="fa fa-cc-visa icon-button"></i>
      <h5 class="text-button">Clienti con Modalita' di Pagamento Carta Credito</h5>
    </button>
  </a>
</div>
```

This function is incorrect because it does not return what I asked for.

```
function loadPage(){
    var newURL = window.location.pathname;
    window.open(newURL);
}
```

Comment: Your description is very confusing.  Are you running code in the parent window that's trying to find the src of the iframe?  Or are you trying to run code inside the iframe that returns its src (...to what? The parent? The iframe?)

Comment: Wrapping a button with an anchor is invalid HTML.  Per [the MDN anchor reference section on permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#properties): _"no descendant may be interactive content or an `a` element"_  While this may not _necessarily_ be the source of your issue, malformed and/or invalid HTML can generate all sorts of difficult to debug issues.  I would recommend envisioning a different approach that leverages a valid HTML structure before tackling whatever issue it is you are having.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: @DanielBeck 
I'm trying to print the url of the button once clicked on the page where it is contained. Let me explain I have a page called sem_menu.html, inside there is an iframe with the page sem_menu2.html which in turn contains a series of buttons. my final result must be that pressing one of those buttons returns me by printing in the form of text and link the exact position of its corresponding href.

Comment: you don't want the iframe href ? you want the href of the page containing the iframe right ?

Comment: That didn't really clear anything up.  The button's inside the iframe, ok, but 1) where is the code that reads the URL? (parent window or inside the iframe?)  2) which URL are you trying to retrieve (the parent or the iframe?). 3) Where do you want to display the url (parent or iframe?)

Comment: the code that reads the url is inside the frame. I am trying to retrieve the url of the button contained within a page loaded in iframe and I have to print this url on the page where the frame was loaded

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] and take the [tour] to best understand how to get useful guidance from the community. Thanks you for including a [mcve] in your question. Additionally, to add clarity, could you update the question to more clearly specify the desired behavior, and also include the actual behavior (and how the two differ)?  This might help clear up some of the confusion occurring in the comments, and better enable the community to help you. Good luck, and happy coding!